# How to exclude directory from Sublime Text search?

Tags: sublime-text

I would like to exclude certain directory from search results in Sublime Text 3.

I've tried different combinations of syntax such us:

-app\storage*
"app\storage*"
-"D:/htdocs/app/storage/*"

but none of them worked

Comment: Please note that this site is about recommending software *for* specific needs – not about solving issues you have *with* certain software. So this question is off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

Here's syntax that works:

-app/storage/*

**storage** directory along with all sub-directories will not be searched